# Making my Discord Bot automatically play music from WAV on loop

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord, bots

So I was trying to make a Discord Bot in Python, which would atomatically join a voice channel and play my own music from a list in a loop. So far it's joining the channel, shuffling the list so the music is on random, but when I try to write a code so after one song it will play the next one it crushes and doesn't play anything (tho it's joining the channel)

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio

#playlist as a list
queue = [FFmpegPCMAudio('Iceland1.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Iceland2.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Iceland3.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Iceland4.wav'),
         FFmpegPCMAudio('Iceland5.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Iceland6.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Iceland7.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Iceland8.wav'),
         FFmpegPCMAudio('Iceland9.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Iceland10.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Norway1.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Norway2.wav'),
         FFmpegPCMAudio('Norway3.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Norway4.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Norway5.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Norway6.wav'),
         FFmpegPCMAudio('Norway7.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Norway8.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Norway9.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Norway10.wav'),
         FFmpegPCMAudio('Norway11.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Presents1.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Presents2.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Presents3.wav'),
         FFmpegPCMAudio('Presents4.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Presents5.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Presents6.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Presents7.wav'),
         FFmpegPCMAudio('Presents8.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Presents9.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Presents10.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Autumn1.wav'),
         FFmpegPCMAudio('Autumn2.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Autumn3.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Autumn4.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Autumn5.wav'),
         FFmpegPCMAudio('Autumn6.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Autumn7.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Autumn8.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Covers1.wav'),
         FFmpegPCMAudio('Covers2.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Covers3.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Covers4.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Covers5.wav'),
         FFmpegPCMAudio('Covers6.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Covers7.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Covers8.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Covers9.wav'),
         FFmpegPCMAudio('Covers10.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Covers11.wav'), FFmpegPCMAudio('Covers12.wav')]

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global voice
    print("The Matt Bot is ready")
    print("--------------------------")
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('Matt Krupa')) #makes my bot play Matt Krupa
    channel = client.get_channel(thechannelid) #geting channel ID
    voice = await channel.connect() #connecting to channel
    random.shuffle(queue) #randomazing the playlist
    def after_song(): #moving the first song to the end so its on loop, and playling the next one
        queue.append(queue[0])
        del queue[0]
        player = await voice.play(queue[0], after=await after_song())
    player = await voice.play(queue[0], after=await after_song()) #plays song from the playlist, after the song doing the after_song() function

client.run(mytokenidontwanttoshowitsry)
```

I wanted it to play all the songs on the infinite loop, i can't find how to correctly detect the end of a song...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
after=await, after_song()
```

This could be the problem as it may not recognise the space between the 2 parameters

Comment: No it's not the thing